# How to programmatically limit bandwidth usage of my c# application?

Tags: c#, limit, bandwidth, throttling

I've got a backup application here which connects to various webservices and downloads/uploads files from ftp or http servers. What is the easiest way to limit the bandwidth usage of my application?

I need to do that because the application once installed and running will be slowing down internet access for all office people, which eventually will get me into hell. So I'd like to implement a speed-limit which is active during the work-hours and gets disabled at night.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Bandwidth throttling** And here is a **[good example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Bandwidth_throttling.aspx)** how is this done, also review the comments to know how it is done from a client side.

You may also want to take a look at [**this example**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx) too, putting things in a real application