# Create a bandwidth control system

Tags: c#, bandwidth-throttling

I plan to use C# to implement the bandwidth control system.

I need to implement the system that can allow the system user to set a bandwidth rate to the computer user.

How can I do that?

Comment: For your application or for ALL applications?

Comment: Seems like it's for the whole computer, we need more detail about this. Maybe you can edit your question and add more details for us to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can begin to have a look at the following question:
[Limit Bandwidth Speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062357/limit-bandwidth-speeds)

You might also consider having a look at [TokenBucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) and [LeakyBucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) implementations, as well as some [Rate Limiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) concept, for you to implement your own system.