# Download file with limited speed in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core website & I there's a large file to download. So I want to make a limitation for unauthorized users & limit their download speed for that file to 50 kb/s.

I've checked rate limiting solutions, but they didn't do this actually. This is what I want:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Download file with unlimited speed
}
else
{
    // Download file with limited speed
}
```

Comment: This should explain

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling

Comment: Have your tried to limit your bandwidth usage? You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847422/how-to-programmatically-limit-bandwidth-usage-of-my-c-sharp-application).